# What do I need to edit to get this reopened?

Tags: discussion, moderation

talking about this: [How much can you trust a (banking) site after it spams you?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31017/how-much-can-you-trust-a-banking-company-after-it-spams-you)

I seem to still not know what exactly do I need to edit to match the site standards, and stop receiving negative votes.

Please suggest (or even edit).

Thanks.

Comment: One way to make your question better would simply be to ask the specific company you have in mind what they're doing to remedy what they've done, and how it happened in the first place. Then, compare that with what people on here recommend companies *should* do under the given set of circumstances. If they were hacked, this falls under IT Security. If they just sold information... it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

I think the question is too subjective to be a good fit for this site.  What do you want us to say?  How are you going to evaluate the answer?  The questions invites opinions, but not the good kind of opinions (opinions that can be backed up with evidence).  Put another way, the answers will tell us more about the views of the answerer than about any objective truth.

Consequently, I don't think this question is a good fit for IT Security, and I don't see any way that editing will save it.

Stack Exchange sites are a bit different from many other discussion forums; we're not looking for open-ended questions or discussion.  Instead, we're looking to have archival-quality questions and answers of value to others, and we have certain criteria that we expect our questions to abide by.  See the FAQ for more details on those criteria.

Comment: I was looking for an answer along the lines of "its a bad practice" , or "its a huge security risk" . -- I want to know in situations like this, what is the proper action to take or what to think of this company. -- the one answer posted so far is of great help imo, I just wanted to see more info.